# How did the "erogation" word end up on displays of coffee machines?

Tags: etymology, nouns, latin

According to many dictionaries, *erogation* comes from the Latin for "the art of giving out or bestowing", but currently seems to be heavily linked to the coffee business. I'd like to know how this happened.

Comment: You should ask on [English.SE] instead.

Comment: Why? I'm interested about the change of the meaning of erogation through the History, but not limited to an english-centric point of view.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search turned up a (slightly broken) page with [a blog post](http://www.couriermail.com.au/ipad/how-to-erogate-your-coffee/story-fn6ck8la-1225961644956) about this very topic.

The author was curious about that word in the context of an espresso machine's LED display. The author's hypothesis, which I find quite plausible, is that the word is a mistranslation of the Italian verb *erogare*, meaning 'to deliver, to supply (water, electricity, gas)'.  In the author's words:

> "Who makes coffee machines? Italians. What do they speak? Italian..."